# 170016 error pushing flask app to Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm trying to push a flask app to Bluemix, but receiving the following error:

```
{
  "code": 170016,
  "description": "Runner error: desire app failed: 400",
  "error_code": "CF-RunnerError"
}
```

The command:

```
CF_TRACE=true cf push
```

By cf tooling version:

```
$ cf --version
cf version 6.26.0+9c9a261fd.2017-04-06
```

The logs show:

```
API/0Created app with guid xxxx Apr 18, 2017 6:16:00 PM
API/0Updated app with guid xxxx ({"name"=>"movie-recommend-demo-dublin", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>0, "memory"=>128, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "health_check_timeout"=>180})Apr 18, 2017 6:21:31 PM
API/2Updated app with guid xxxx ({"route"=>"xxxx", :verb=>"add", :relation=>:routes, :related_guid=>"xxxx"})Apr 18, 2017 6:21:35 PM
API/1Updated app with guid xxxx ({"name"=>"movie-recommend-demo-dublin", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>0, "memory"=>128, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "health_check_timeout"=>180})Apr 18, 2017 6:22:28 PM
API/0Updated app with guid xxxx ({"name"=>"movie-recommend-demo-dublin", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "instances"=>0, "memory"=>128, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "health_check_timeout"=>180})Apr 18, 2017 6:26:15 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was writing this question, I realised that I had a typo in my manifest.yml

```
instances: 0
```

Hopefully this will help other users find the issue quicker if they have similar typos.